# Commutative ring as a direct limit of Noetherian rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

Does there exist a directed set $\mathcal J$ such that every commutative ring with unity is a direct limit of a family of (commutative) Noetherian rings indexed by $\mathcal J$ ?

Comment: The second statement is certainly true: every ring is the colimit of its finitely generated subrings, which are Noetherian.

Comment: @JHF: ah yes true indeed ... I have edited my question only to address the first part I asked accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  For instance, consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[S]$ where $S$ is an arbitrary infinite set of indeterminates.  Then any Noetherian subring $R_0\subset R$ can only contain finitely many elements of $S$ (otherwise the ideal generated by $R_0\cap S$ would not be finitely generated).  It follows that $R$ cannot be a direct limit of a system of Noetherian rings indexed by $\mathcal{J}$ for any $\mathcal{J}$ of cardinality less than $|S|$, and so no fixed $\mathcal{J}$ can work for all $S$.

Comment: Could you please explain why does it follow that the indexing set can't have cardinality less than $|S|$ ?

Comment: The image in $R$ of each ring in the directed system contains only finitely many elements of $S$.  So for their union to contain all of $S$, there must be at least $|S|$ of them.

Comment: Ah so you're using the actual construction of direct limit right ...? Thanks !

Comment: Might I ask a related question here ..? Does there exist a small category $\mathcal J$ such that every commutative ring is the colimit of some diagram of $\mathcal J$ whose objects are all Noetherian ..? Your answer shows that we cannot take $\mathcal J$ to be the category obtained from a directed set and its ordering ...

Comment: I think the answer is no and the same example $R=\mathbb{Z}[S]$ can be used.  It would suffice to show that any Noetherian subring of $R$ is contained in $\mathbb{Z}[S_0]$ for some finite subset $S_0\subset S$.  I think that should be true but the proof is more complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I think I have a proof for that.  It's a bit complicated to write out in the comments; I can elaborate in an answer to a new question if you want.

Comment: I have asked a new question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109356/commutative-rings-as-co-limit-of-noetherian-rings